# Visual studio 2015 refactor method signature

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

When adding a parameter to a method call, VS refactoring suggest to create new overloaded method with empty implementation.

Is it possible to change the existing method implementation by adding a parameter to the method?

For example:
Assuming method A is:

```
public void A(int i)
{
   Console.Debug(i)
}
```

And this method is called:

```
 A(5);
```

and this changed to

```
A(5,"string");
```

now I want to change the method to be:

```
public void A(int i,string s)
{
   Console.Debug(i)
}
```

rather than that a new overloaded is created with not implemented exception:

```
public void A(int i,string s)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio can't do that but Resharper can.

[Resharper suggest you to modify the existing implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n6cW.png)

Visual studio as an IDE it won't deeply suggest like how Resharper does. Resharper is specifically to  ease the way of refactoring and specially to adore coding standards.